Dot parameters LTspice - Transconductance of MOSFET
Below is a very simple circuit to extract the transconductance value of the MOSFET.
As it is known, transconductance is known as Delta (Id) / Delta (Vgate).
For the gate voltage, I defined it as .step param X 0 12 0.5.
To make ΔID/ΔVGS and get the result of transconductance ı write dot parameters as follow:
.param Vhigh {X}
.param Vlow {X-0.5}
.save V(Vg) Id(M1)
.meas TRAN Id_high FIND Id(M1) WHEN V(Vg)=Vhigh
.meas TRAN Id_low FIND Id(M1) WHEN V(Vg)=Vlow
.meas TRAN gm PARAM (Id_high-Id_low)/(Vhigh-Vlow)
.print gm
When ı check the Spice error log , Id_high - Id_low and gm  values are negative. Why ? What is wrong with my dot parameters ?


Source: https://www.mouser.com.tr/datasheet/2/240/media-3322045.pdf



Are you trying to plot the transconductance or get a text output of it?

I am trying to get transconductance, but ı am not sure how to do it with dot parameters @Ste Kulov

@V.V.T  thank you for your comments. I know the formula but ı dont know how to plot it with dot parameters in ltspice. This is the point that I am looking for to create ΔID/ΔVGS

I can't tell if this is what you want or something else.  https://i.sstatic.net/32eeV9lD.png

how to define ΔID/ΔVGS with dot parameters. This is what ı am looking for. @Ste Kulov

Like this?  https://i.sstatic.net/AJxlQQt8.png

Unfortunately no @Ste Kulov

Then I don't understand what you want.  Sorry.

transconductance is a value as ı indicated many times ΔID/ΔVGS, your schematic is I-V plot, And I said in the question that ı need dot parameters which show me the transconductance @Ste Kulov but thank you for your explanations.

No, you misread my plots.  I was plotting d(Id), which is ΔID/ΔVGS.  Please look closer.  The d( ) function takes derivative with respect to what's on the x-axis.  My first plot is the preferred way to do it.  As you can see the units are ohm^-1, which is conductance.

Okay ı understant your point. Could you plot the d(Id))/d(Vgs)) on the Y-axis and Id on the X-axis. I tried it but nothing is shown. I add a sample graph of a real mosfet above to check how does it look like @Ste Kulov

Can you also show the transient plots of these Id(M1) transient curves? and point to which current values are assigned to your Id_low and Id_high variables?

Okay sir , I added the Id(M1) and Id_low and Id_high results which is contained in spice error log @Designalog

Made with microcap v12
Something like this. Note that it is only d(Id) versus Vgs.

Should get something like this ...


Hello sir, yes its something like this and ı add a real transconductance of a mosfet in the question you can check it above. In the X-axis we need ID and on the Y-axis transconductance which is ΔID/ΔVGS. But ı dont know how to plot it especially with dot parameters  @Antonio51

additionally adding an algebraic expression to the plot doesn't work. I add  d(Id))/d(Vgs))  on Y-axis and Id on X-axis it didnt show me anything @Antonio51

Sorry. Don't know LTSpice very well.

@Mhan In your circuit you need to use node names which actually exist. That would be d(Id(M1))/d(V(Vg)). But x-axis is already Vgs so d(V(Vg)) will be one. Only way to change x-axis is to change what parameter you sweep. If you want to have Id on x-axis, you need to sweep Id directly.

Hello @SteKulov thank you for your comments. can you show how to sweep Id if ı want to have Id on x-axis and transconductance on y-axis.

What's probably going on is that there's a brief period close to 0s in your transient where the current goes negative, and since it coincides with the points where your input voltage is high or low, then this is what's being recorded. And that's why your recorded current values are negative, despite your Id(M1) transient curve looking mostly positive. The parts where the current goes negative can't be well appreciated at this scale.
Anyhow, I think the method you're using to find out gm is not the right one.
Why don't you, instead, simply sweep the gate voltage (which equals Vgs since the source is grounded) and plot Id(M1) as a function of it.
Then, all you need to do is plot d(Id(M1)) (it'll be plotted as a function of Vgs, as it's the only parameter you're sweeping), and you're done.

That’s exactly what I suggested but he said it was wrong. (insert shrugging shoulders emoji)

ı didnt say you are wrong, thank you for your comments but ı said how to do with DOT PARAMETERS @Ste Kulov

@SteKulov oh, didn't read your suggestion. The great minds think alike ;)

@Mhan why are you so adamant in doing it that way? If you must do so then you can also read two points in the IDs vs vgs curve and do the same operations.

@Mhan I showed an example with .step param too. Is that not a “DOT PARAMETER”?
